# CSS transition ease in and ease out different value

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to apply for *CSS* transition different values on hover in ease-in and ease-out.

Like this,

```
ease-in: 180ms,
ease-out: 240ms
```

when I hover it will be 180ms ease-in, but when hovering out it will be 240ms ease-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different **transition-duration** values for the styles affecting your element, for example:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: width 180ms ease-in;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  transition-duration: 240ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div>My Element</div>
```

For more details please check [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)